# Tags in form input?

Tags: php, html

When text with HTML tags inside it are inputted into a web-form (e.g `<em>john</em>`), how does it appear to the PHP processor?

I did some experiments with the example above and found that the form was sending the query string `%3Cem%3Ejohn%3C%2Fem%3E` is that how it would appear?

How could i fix this so that it appears as typed: `<em>john</em>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"%3Cem%3Ejohn%3C%2Fem%3E"

In the above statement % specifies `whitespace`.its browser dependent ,some browser replaces whitespace with '%' and some with '+'

if you want to decode than you can do that by php function `rawurldecode();`
the syntax of which is `string rawurldecode ( string $str ).`

Now about querystring:

when you are sending your data via GET method,the data which you send is formed into "name=value" form and its goes to the server.

example:

consider you have a form like this

```
<form method="get" action="a.php">
name:<input type="text" name="name">
</form>
```

and you insert name as rahul

then the query string will be "name=rahul" ,the value of which you can retreive in the server side using `$_GET` or `$_REQUEST`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [rawurldecode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rawurldecode.php) function to decode the string.

```
rawurldecode("%3Cem%3Ejohn%3C%2Fem%3E")
```

Answer (score 0):

A string in which all non-alphanumeric characters except -_. have been replaced with a percent `(%)` sign followed by two hex digits and spaces encoded as plus (+) signs. It is encoded the same way that the posted data from a WWW form is encoded, that is the same way as in application/x-www-form-urlencoded media type. This differs from the » RFC 3986 encoding (see rawurlencode()) in that for historical reasons, spaces are encoded as plus (+) signs.  It is an encoded, *To get an typed content, you can use `urldecode()`*

```
$str  ='<em>john</em>';
echo $Encoded = urlencode ( $str ); //OP %3Cem%3Ejohn%3C%2Fem%3E

echo urldecode ( $Encoded );
```